# UIStroyboard segue issue

Tags: objective-c, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I created story board App. Actually I have issuw with segue. I have one "A" view controller, and segue is suppose to push "B" viewcontroller. In "A" viewController, we are expecting some userInfo and we are performing some validations for that, and based on validation only it should push new viewController through segue. My issue is, I used triggered segue and it always push "B" view controller. Can you please inform me based on validations, how can I disable segue.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the button from Scene A.  Not from a UI Element on Scene A, but from the base view of Scene A.

Now, in Scene A's view controller, if you've got a button that's supposed to validate, just use an `if` or whatever.  If all the info is good, call the segue, if it's not, don't call the segue.

Call the segue like this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"MySegue" sender: self];
```

Where `@"MySegue"` is replaced with the name you gave your segue on the storyboard.

---

For example:

```
- (IBAction) myButtonPress:(id)sender {
    //validate the info
    if(valid) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"MySegue" sender: self];
    } else {
        //probably prompt the user that their info is invalid
        //maybe clear textboxes, etc.
    }
}
```

They key here though is attaching the segue from the `viewController`, and not from the button itself.  You also have to be sure to name your segue, and be sure the name on storyboard matches the name in code.  XCode won't help you autocomplete it.